# Should I implement File Dialog as Singleton?

Tags: java, swing, singleton, openfiledialog

I'm developing a swing based application where I'm using many FileDialogs? So I say why not to make just one FileDialog object instead all of these instances and use it in the whole project? Is this a good assumption? does this have any performance improvement?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a great example of a use case where application performance doesn't really matter and the question actually falls into the premature optimization class of problem solving. Why? Using FileDialog means that you are interacting with the user who, even if skilled beyond skilled with shortcut key Kung Fu, will be many orders of magnitude slower than the application. How many FileDialogs could a speedy user open, use and close in one minute? Say a dozen. You should not need to care about a dozen objects coming and going in one minute. Shouldn't even appear on your radar. Use your energies elsewhere. In fact, you should create a new object every time and avoid any caching headaches.

Comment: +1 very nicely said and strong point with the premature optimization.

Answer (score 3):

I would make a static FileDialog class that generates a new instance of the FileDialog each time a new one needs open rather than sharing a Singleton instance across the application.

That'll save you the headache of trying to figure out if you're reading the correct path from the dialog box or if somebody has opened the dialog and picked a new path and now you're referencing that new path rather than the originally selected path, etc...

Answer (score 1):

Why implement is as a Singleton?  Can you actually verify that displaying two file dialogs will never occur?

Better to have it as a regular class; you don't want to build in limitations which could become pain points later.

It isn't like your application is going to be critically overloaded by millions of calls to the file dialog, and who knows, perhaps someday it will be the right solution to have two file dialogs.  Even if you don't display them both at the same time, perhaps holding the history in a "source" dialog and having a separate history in the "destination" dialog would be a blessing in a file transfer program.

Answer (score 0):

Forget performance/speedyness. It doesn't matter here. Semantics matter. Reusing the same file dialog may give you things for free. Will the dialog start in the same directory every time? It will if it is the same instance. If you are creating new dialogs you will have to set startup dir your self.

Also why make it impossible to create more than one instance? Just make an instance member in your frame and be done with it.